# Как еще можно сделать привязку ListView к Adarter?

Tags: c#, listview

Пытаюсь создать динамическое добавление списка Listview. Нашла решение на java. Вроде все работает, но вот привязку сделать не получается. Пишу в Xamarin на C#, он выдает, что SetAdapter устарел. ;(
Опиралась на это решение: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php

Comment: @svetlana, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Xamarin намекает вам, что вместо

```
myListview.SetAdapter(adapter)
```

Вы должны использовать синтаксис сеттера, то есть что-то вроде

```
myListview.Adapter = adapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) Как-то так, получается  (http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.10/level_17_diff/mono.android.dll/)

Namespace Android.Widget

Type Changed: Android.Widget.AbsListView
Added properties:

```
public override IListAdapter Adapter { get; set; }
```

Removed methods:

```
public virtual void SetAdapter (IListAdapter adapter);
```

Added methods:

```
[Obsolete ("Please use the Adapter property setter")]  
public virtual void SetAdapter (IListAdapter adapter);
```